# Integration/synchronization pattern

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-eventhub

We are designing synchronization between SAP and Salesforce.

Our architect propose pattern to use Azure Service Bus between them:
[image]

Our client want to use Azure Event Hub instead Azure Service Bus for this.

[image]

And client told us, that Event Hub is must have for that.
Reading documentation in my opinion Azure Service Bus should better fit for synchronization like Point-to-Point (from SAP database to Salesforce database).
Can somebody explain, why Event Hub can be better for synchronization like this? 
What is good point for our client to use it?
Should we try to convince our client to change architecture to Service Bus?
I really didn't made integration using Event Hub so I don't know what should I expect for that.

Comment: Did the client tell why he thinks Event Hub is a must have?

Comment: @PeterBons not yet, tomorrow I will have meeting with client architect. But I want to have some point of my vision for this architecture, so I asking is Event Hub better approach for this solution instead Service Bus?

Comment: Event Hub is for large scale message processing. Things like ordering are harder to get right since it is optimized for speed. Choice could depened on the amount and frequency of the messages.

Comment: You haven't provided enough details to tell which service fits best however I should say Service Bus and Event Hubs solve different business problems. Here is a comparison doc you can go through with your client - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/compare-messaging-services